# Make UILabel Text Clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, tttattributedlabel

I want to make clickable some specific text on `UILabel` e.g: `@"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing bla bla"`

In this string `"Ipsum,dummy,printing"` should be clickable and also its color should be change. I tried this with `TTTAttributedLabel` (custom class) but its only  changing the color.

Please give me any useful suggestion.

Comment: yes you go with custom button and on touchupainside change the background of button.

Comment: I haven't used this, but you can just give a quick try.http://maniacdev.com/2012/12/open-source-library-for-easily-creating-a-uilabel-with-clickable-words

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `Three20` library now. Use core text based `RTLabel`

https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel

```
RTLabel *html = [[RTLabel alloc]init];
html.delegate = self;
strHTML.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" <font face=TrebuchetMS size=%i>Unlimited searches of ICD-10-CM Search apps for iPad, iPhone, and iTouch.\n<a href='%@'><font color=#0094fa>%@</font></a> per month</font>", DESC_FONT, @"m", @"$2.99"];
html.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, TEXT_WIDTH, ROW_HEIGHT);
[html setLineSpacing:5];
[html setLineBreakMode:RTTextLineBreakModeWordWrapping];
[html setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[html setText:strHTML];
[html setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:html];
```

And here is its delegate method:

```
- (void)rtLabel:(id)rtLabel didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
}
```

Your label will look like this:

[image]